# Faulty If, Else Statement

Tags: r

I always get the the Error: unexpected 'else' in "     else" in my If, Else Statement.

Pls help I've been sitting with this Error since two days and need to finish my paper till tomorrow.

```
Isflorida <- function(data) {
  data <- filter(data,is.na(State)== FALSE)
  data$Isflorida <- vector(mode = "logical", length = nrow(data)) 
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) { 
    if (data[i,]$State == "Florida") {
      data[i,]$Isflorida <- TRUE }
    else {data[i,]$Isflorida <- FALSE}}data}
```

Comment: I think the asignment  would be `if(data$State[i] == "Florida") data$Isflorida[i] <- TRUE` or you don't really need the `if/else i.e. `data$isfloridda[i]<- data$State[i] == "Florida")`  Also, note that `==` is vectorized so,  the  `for` loop is not needed

Comment: I don't really understand what you want.  Are you just looking for a variable Isflorida which is true or false

Comment: For idiomatic (and perhaps more efficient) code, I suggest you convert `is.na(State)==FALSE` to `!is.na(State)`.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that be enough?

```
data$IsFlorida <- ifelse(data$State=="Florida", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: @akrun Thanks ;)

Comment: You can shorten this to `data$IsFlorida <- data$State=="Florida"`

Answer (score 0):

Do not add `data` right after `}`, if really want to, add a semi-colon.

```
Isflorida <- function(data) {
  data <- filter(data,is.na(State)== FALSE)
  data$Isflorida <- vector(mode = "logical", length = nrow(data)) 
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) { 
    if (data[i,]$State == "Florida") {
      data[i,]$Isflorida <- TRUE } 
    else {data[i,]$Isflorida <- FALSE}}; data}
```

I would think that most R users will use more lines, like so:

```
Isflorida <- function(data) {
  data <- filter(data,is.na(State)== FALSE)
  data$Isflorida <- vector(mode = "logical", length = nrow(data)) 
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) { 
    if (data[i,]$State == "Florida") {
      data[i,]$Isflorida <- TRUE 
    } else {data[i,]$Isflorida <- FALSE}
  }
  data
}
```

Comment: BTW, I agree with previous answer/comment that there may be simpler ways to do what you're looking for (IIUC).